# I tried to make an animation of a 3D ball. There is no error message, but there's no animation at all. Why?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, manipulate

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
m=10;
F = 5;
wys=0.25;

f[alfa_, beta_, , walfa_, wbeta_ , l_, g_,p_] :=
Module[{sol_alfa, sol_beta},
sol_alfa = NDSolveValue[{-10 *l*(g *Cos[\[Beta][t]] *Sin[\[Alpha][t]]+l *Cos[\[Alpha][t]]* Sin[\[Alpha][t]] *(\[Beta]'[t])^2+l *\[Alpha]''[t])==0,\[Alpha][0]==alfa,\[Alpha]'[0]==walfa},\[Alpha], {t,p-1,p}, MaxSteps->100000];
sol_beta = NDSolveValue[{-10 *l* Cos[\[Alpha][t]] (g* Sin[\[Beta][t]]-2 *l* Sin[\[Alpha][t]] *\[Alpha]'[t]* \[Beta]'[t]+l *Cos[\[Alpha][t]] *\[Beta]''[t])==0,\[Beta][0]==beta,\[Beta]'[0]==wbeta},\[Beta], {t,p-1,p}, MaxSteps->100000]
Show[Graphics3D[Black, Sphere[{l * Cos[sol_alfa[p]] * Cos[sol_beta[p]],l * Cos[sol_alfa[p]] * Sin[sol_beta[p]], l * Sin[sol_alfa[p]]  }, 0.3], Axes -> True], PlotRange->{{-5,5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}]];

Manipulate[
f[alfa, beta, walfa, wbeta, l, g, p], {{g, 9.8, "gravitational acceleration"}, 1, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
{{alfa, 0, "starting alpha"}, -Pi/2, Pi/2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},  
{{beta, 0, "starting beta"}, -Pi, Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{walfa, 0, "starting alpha velocity"}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
{{wbeta, 0, "starting beta velocity"}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},  
{{l, 0, "length of pendulum"}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
{{p, 0, "animation"}, 0, Infinity, ControlType -> Trigger}]
```

For some reasons, it only shows this:

[image]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, there is no error message at all.

Comment: 1. `_` is a built-in function in Mathematica, you cannot use it for variable name. 2. `beta_, , walfa_`  is obviouly wrong. Please settle down and double check your code carefully.

Comment: Typo in your definition of `f`; extra comma after `beta_`.  Then check if `f` runs before putting it in `Manipulate`.

Comment: Also, check the initial conditions and boundary for your equations, it's underdetermined.

Comment: @xzczd Where am I using _ as a variable name?

Comment: You're not using it as a variable name, you're using it inside variable names: `Module[{sol_alfa, sol_beta},`

Comment: `_` is always a `Blank` (a pattern matching concept) in Mathematica, which has a special meaning. Well, it doesn't have a special meaning inside a string, but you can't use strings as variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Here we rewrite the code to a ODE system.The code work. But we still need the questionor fix the physical meaning.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
f[alfa_, beta_, walfa_, wbeta_, l_, g_, p_] := 
  Module[{sol, solalfa, solbeta}, 
   sol = NDSolveValue[{-10*
        l*(g*Cos[β[t]]*Sin[α[t]] + 
          l*Cos[α[t]]*Sin[α[t]]*(β'[t])^2 + 
          l*α''[t]) == 
       0, -10*l*
        Cos[α[t]] (g*Sin[β[t]] - 
          2*l*Sin[α[t]]*α'[t]*β'[t] + 
          l*Cos[α[t]]*β''[t]) == 0, α[0] == 
       alfa, α'[0] == walfa, β[0] == beta, β'[0] ==
        wbeta}, {α, β}, {t, p - 1, p}, 
     MaxSteps -> 100000];
   {solalfa, solbeta} = sol;
   Graphics3D[{Black, 
     Sphere[{l*Cos[solalfa[p]]*Cos[solbeta[p]], 
       l*Cos[solalfa[p]]*Sin[solbeta[p]], l*Sin[solalfa[p]]}, 0.3]}, 
    Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}]];
Manipulate[
 f[alfa, beta, walfa, wbeta, l, g, 
  p], {{g, 9.8, "gravitational acceleration"}, 1, 100, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{alfa, 0, "starting alpha"}, -Pi/2, Pi/2,
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{beta, 0, "starting beta"}, -Pi, Pi, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{walfa, 0, 
   "starting alpha velocity"}, -10, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{wbeta, 0, 
   "starting beta velocity"}, -10, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{l, 1, "length of pendulum"}, .1, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{p, 0, "animation"}, 0, Infinity, 
  ControlType -> Trigger}]
```